# Generalizing open subsets to $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ then $X\times Y$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$. State and prove a generalization to $\Bbb{R}^n$.

I figure the best approach is just to start with the generalization.

So if $X_1,...,X_n$ are open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$ then $X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$ are open subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Prove this statement.

This is where I'm struggling to figure out what to prove exactly. Do I use open balls? Or perhaps the complement? I solved a similar problem involving proving all subsets were closed.

Comment: Hint: What do the elements of the basis of your product topology look like?

Comment: Is it perhaps the sequence $\{x_1^{(k)},...,x_n^{(k)}\}$? @Ziryerx

Comment: You have a typo.$X_i $ are open subsets of R.  Not R^n.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to give a big hint on doing it for $n=2$, and you can work on the generalization.

How do you show a subset $U$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is open? You should that given $x\in U$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(x)$, the ball of radius $r$, is contained in $U$.

To this end, let $(x,y)\in X\times Y$. Then there exists $r_1>0$ such that $B_{r_1}(x)\subseteq X$ (why?). Similarly there exists $r_2>0$ such that $B_{r_2}(y)\subseteq Y$.

Now, we need an open ball in $\Bbb R^2$. Take a suitable choice of $r$ (really your only candidate is either the minimum or maximum of $\{r_1,r_2\}$), and try to show that $B_r((x,y))\subseteq X\times Y$. It may be easier to show that $B_r((x,y))\subseteq B_{r_1}(x)\times B_{r_2}(y)$.

Answer (score 3):

Can you prove that if $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in O = (a_1,b_1) \times (a_2, b_2) \times \ldots \times (a_n, b_n)$ there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset O$?

Comment: Since $X$ is open, is $B(x,r) \subset O$ implied?

Comment: You have to prove it's open.